# Json objects are not properly appearing in Attivio Search

Tags: json, attivio

I have imported a Json file in Attivio and indexed it for search. When I search the content in Search UI, it shows whole Json data as single field instead of extracting all the fields out of it and then indexing all these fields.

It would be great if somebody can help me in indexing the file on the basis of json fields.
Please find below screenshot of search UI for indexed json file:
[image]

Comment: Show us what you have tried(?)

Comment: @M.K M.K .. I have imported a Json file in Attivio and indexed it. The whole content of the file is being shown as one string field in Attivio search UI. Please see attached screenshot.